# how do i fetch an href tag belonging to an anchor tag of particular class within div tag? in python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**Python Code :**

```
productLinks = [div.a for div in 
        soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'a-row a-spacing-none'})]
print(productLinks)
for link in productLinks:
    print(hr.append(link['href']))
```

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\api.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(hr.append(link['href']))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Could you add the html snippet that you used in the variable ```soup``` ?

Comment: <div class="a-row a-spacing-none"><a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  visited-title a-text-normal" title="Dell Inspiron 3558 Notebook (5th Gen Intel Core i3- 4GB RAM- 1TB HDD- 39.62 cm(15.6)- Ubuntu) (Black)" href="http://www.amazon.in/Dell-Inspiron-3558-Notebook-Ubuntu/dp/B01GHGLL2G/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1477750545&amp;sr=1-1&amp;keywords=dell+laptops"><h2 data-attribute="Dell Inspiron 3558 Notebook (5th Gen Intel Core i3- 4GB RAM- 1TB HDD- 39.62 cm(15.6)- Ubuntu) (Black)" data-max-rows="0" data-truncate-by-character="false" class="a-size-basel">…</h2></a></div>